# Google plus circles database logic

Tags: php, database, database-design, google-plus, geometry

So i recnetly started to play around with the idea to create a similar circle system in my site like google plus.

But the bad part is that im not too good at planing databases.

So i want on googles site to gather some info, and i saw for every user it has unique circle id's.

So my idea what this.

I have the users, and storing them this way.

```
users
users_metadata
users_settings
```

`users` table containt the pass, username, email, last login and basic stuff
`users_metadata` contains the inf ofor their profile
`users_settings` contains ther settings options

So when an user registers to the site, in the `users_metadata` and `users_settings the current user`id` will be inserted.

So my queston is, is it a good idea to create an `users_circles` table for every user, with default options?

I was thinking this because it will give them easier ability to create their own groups and delete groups what they dont like.

Or could someone show me a better logic? if its not a big request.

Thank you

Comment: It's "not a big request" to tell you how to implement BigTable on your relational database?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal for one table per person is, to be blunt, a bad idea. It might work "ok" when you have a few uses, but if this scales to any level it will be both a programming and a database management nightmare, not to mention a horrible waste of resources.

This is a perfect case where you should have a users_groups table where every users' group exists. Each group would have its own id, of course, and the owner of the group (the user). Selecting on the group would return multiple rows - the members of the group.

This is what relational databases are GOOD at.

Take advantage of that.

Comment: Perhaps even better is if you have a groups_metadata which would be what contained the owner of the group, along with the name and any other info, leaving the groups table to just have the groupID and all of the member ids.

Comment: this is what i was thkining too, but looks like i wasnt clear, sorry about that. So the ide was like this at first, what you said and when they sign up, it creates the 5 different groups with unique id, and place the users id there too, and thank you fro your reply